# database not responding after a limit

Tags: mysql, database

I have an problem in fetching records from database with php.

I have 31700 records in database. when i fetches records from this query:

> select * from product_likes

Then, script was aborted and blank page was showing.but when i use limit in query (i.e. "select * from product_likes limit 0, 12000;") then it is giving upto 12000 records.

And when i fecthes records from this query:

> select product_name, like_count from product_likes

Then, script was aborted and blank page was showing.but when i use limit in query (i.e. "select product_name, like_count from product_likes limit 0, 30000;") then it is giving upto 30000 records.

I can't understand where is the problem. And still i can't fetch all records.

Please let me know the reason, How can i overcome this problem...

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to batch your results?  You really need more than 30 THOUSAND records at once?  You can't make multiple queries?

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch all records at once.

Comment: How are you running the query? MySQL command line, phpMyAdmin, something else? What version of MySQL? Can you post DDL and a few INSERT statments so we can try to reproduce the problem? Can you edit your question and include the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT * from product_likes`?

Comment: I am running this query in a php program and want to show all results on a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to modify some server variables like PHP's `memory_limit` and MySQL's `max_allowed_packet`. But I wouldn't show that many items in a single page. Your server will not respond after more than a few visitors start to visit your web page.

Answer (score 0):

> I am running this query in a php program and want to show all results on a web page

There's just so much wrong with this statement its hard to know where to start.

Use 'LIMIT' in your query to retrieve the data a page at a time - and only show one page at a time.

And learn how to use a different tool which does not run in PHP (e.g. the mysql command line client) so you can seperate issues in your code from issues in your data from issues in the tools you are using.